# Order swift array by custom property with condition and secondarily custom property desc

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of a custom object. This object contains a property endDate.

I need to be able to order my array in a way which would be similar to below for sql:

```
order by enddate = 0 desc, enddate desc
```

I know how to do the second part:

```
arr.sorted(by : {$0.enddate > $1.enddate})
```

but I don't know how to sort by enddate conditionally

**Input**

```
[{x: "blah", enddate : 123456}, {x: "blah2", enddate : 234567}, {x: "blah3", enddate : 345678}, {x: "blah4", enddate : 0}]
```

So I would like to have the **output** to have the enddate descending except when the enddate is 0 e.g. `0, 345678, 234567, 123456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing these kinds of custom sorting orders, you should bear in mind the semantic requirements of the sorting predicate that you pass to `sorted(by:)`. These requirements are listed [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907222-sorted):

> The predicate must be a *strict weak ordering* over the elements. That
> is, for any elements a, b, and c, the following conditions must hold:
>
> - `areInIncreasingOrder(a, a)` is always `false`. (Irreflexivity)
> - If `areInIncreasingOrder(a, b)` and `areInIncreasingOrder(b, c)` are both `true`, then `areInIncreasingOrder(a, c)` is also `true`. (Transitive
>   comparability)
> - Two elements are *incomparable* if neither is ordered before the other according to the predicate. If a and b are incomparable, and b and c
>   are incomparable, then a and c are also incomparable. (Transitive
>   incomparability)

Not adhering to these requirements may lead to an incorrectly sorted array. So, bearing those requirements in mind, here's one way to express your sorting order:

```
struct S {
    var endDate: Int
}

let arr = [S(endDate: 123456), S(endDate: 234567), S(endDate: 345678), S(endDate: 0)]

let result = arr.sorted {
    switch ($0.endDate, $1.endDate) {
    case (_, 0):
        return false
    case (0, _):
        return true
    case let (lhs, rhs):
        return lhs > rhs
    }
}

print(result)
// [S(endDate: 0), S(endDate: 345678), S(endDate: 234567), S(endDate: 123456)]
```

The sorting predicate we're using here is:

- Irreflexive: `(0, 0)` is false. Any other `(a, a)` where `a != 0` is also false, as `>` is also irreflexive.
- Transitive comparable: `(0, a)` where `a != 0` is true, and `(a, 0)` is false. Any other combination handled by `>`, which is transitive comparable.
- Transitive incomparable: For a given pair containing at least one `0`, the other element has to be `0` in order to be incomparable. Therefore `a == b == c == 0`, and `(a, c)` is indeed incomparable. Any other combination handled by `>`, which is transitive incomparable.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var sorted = data.sorted { $0.enddate == 0 ? true : $0.enddate > $1.enddate }
```

Comment: Beware that this breaks the requirement of the sorting predicate being a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) – specifically it isn't irreflexive or asymmetric for (0, 0). Therefore you may not get a correctly sorted array back.

Comment: Case in point: Try it with `struct S {var enddate: Int}; let data = [S(enddate: 2), S(enddate: 0), S(enddate: 3)]` – you get back `[S(enddate: 3), S(enddate: 0), S(enddate: 2)]`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Hamish